# Using Angularjs to send and receive data to/from server

Tags: java, angularjs, server

I am taking a computer science course, and currently we are working on a project where we have to build a simple game application. I am working on a tic-tac-toe game where there is a client and a server. Players can sign into the client and connect to the server where they can interact with one another by playing the game.

I am curious if I could build an angularjs web app that can send and receive data from the server (coded in java) to be able to see who is logged into the game, send messages to the chat box, as well as disconnect users from the server.

Is this something that is possible? If so, could anyone link me to some reference materials so that I can learn how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a very broad question and not suited for SO. However, it's certainly possible to build an app like the one you mentioned with AngularJS. I would recommend that you go through their turorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Thank you for the response and reference link. I will be checking it out tomorrow!